# How to build the uncheck command in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my JavaScript code for a checkbox input:

```
var ordineList = [];
$('.chk-ordine').each( function(elIndex, el) {
  if($(el).prop('checked'))
  {
    ordineList.push($(el).attr('data-id'));
  }
});
```

It seems that this code is set only for the check action. Is not for the uncheck. This is the reason why if I try to uncheck the checkbox, the URL doesn't change, and the search remain the same.
Anyone can help me with the uncheck build? If can be helpful, my jQuery version is 3.5.1

Comment: Please show where this code is called within the page. There is nothing in this code that would change the URL for instance, and there is no such thing as a "check action" or a "uncheck action". There is a "click" event, a "change" event, and an "input" event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are having is you aren't using any event listeners, so the code is just running on load and that is it.

```js
 var ordineList;
    
    $(".chk-ordine").on("change",function(){
       ordineList = [];//resets the array so you don't have to worry about adding/removing from the array
        $('.chk-ordine:checked').each( function(elIndex, el) {
            ordineList.push($(el).attr('data-id'));
        });
        console.log(ordineList)
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="chk-ordine" data-id="1"> 1
<input type="checkbox" class="chk-ordine" data-id="2"> 2
<input type="checkbox" class="chk-ordine" data-id="3"> 3
```

Comment: sorry, but this is not the solution. In your case, the ceck don't works :(

Comment: @marcodemurtas, I have updated my answer to show it works.